location of non-local variables of a procedure or function in C
In C, can non-local function and procedure variables be found in the heap and static zone?
in the heap those allocated dynamically, i.e. using malloc and calloc. In the static area, however, there are global variables accessible from all points of the program, right?
in the stack instead there are the local variables of the functions or procedures right?

A static local variable could not be stored on the stack.

In the static area, however, there are global variables accessible from all points of the program, right? Not if the static variable is defined locally. Then its scope is restricted to the function. And if the 'global' variable is static then its scope is limited to that file, not "from all points of the program".

It stored in data segment X86, ARM etc

Video lection with memory segmentation explained

so ,In C,  non-local function and procedure variables are in static zone?

C the language doesn't know about stack or heap. These are implementation details.

@WeatherVane: All objects are accessible throughout a C program during their respective lifetimes. “Access” means to read or write an object, and you can do that if you have its address (except writing a const object, of course). Scope of a name is different from access to an object.

C doesn't have "functions and procedures", it only has functions. So it is somewhat different from languages like Pascal or Basic.

Off-site explanation: What gets allocated on the stack and the heap?

Where objects are stored by C implementations is complicated; it is not solely determined by whether a variable is “local” or not. Two variables defined inside a function, with the same scope for their names, may be stored in different places because one is declared with static and the other is not.
The C standard does not define any variables as “local” or “global.” It does not even use these words to describe variables except one passing instance related to the names of the parameters of main. And the standard does not use the word “procedure” at all.
In C, a variable is composed of two parts: An identifier (name) and memory that is used for the variable. The memory is called an object.
Regardless of where a variable is declared or how an object is created, an object is accessible throughout a program, for the duration of the object’s lifetime. In the C standard, “access” means to read or write an object, and any part of a program can read or write an object if it has the object’s address (except that writing to an object defined with const is not defined).
If you are concerned about “local” and “global” variables, you are likely actually concerned with the scope of the identifier. The scope is the region of program source code where the identifier can be used to refer to its associated object (except when it is hidden by another declaration of the same identifier in an inner scope).
In ordinary general-purpose C implementations, where an object is stored is determined by its storage duration. C has four storage durations:

Automatic storage duration: A function parameter or an object declared inside a function without static has automatic storage duration. These objects are stored on the stack or, due to optimization, held in registers or optimized away (and sometimes a mix of these, including being in different registers or places on the stack at different times).

Thread storage duration: An object declared with _Thread_local has thread storage duration. I have not had occasion to be concerned with where they are stored, but I presume it is in memory allocated when the thread is created.

Static storage duration: An object declared without _Thread_local and either outside a function or inside a function with static has static storage duration. You might think of these as being stored in what you are calling the “static zone.” However, there may be multiple program sections for them. Notably, static objects that are to be initialized to zero may be stored in a program section specifically for that purpose, while static objects with non-zero initial values may be stored in another program section. The zero-filled section is initialized by the operating system when memory for it is provided, so it occupies little space in the program executable. The not-zero-filled section is initialized by reading data from the program executable file into memory.

Allocated storage duration: An object created by calls to the memory management functions, such as malloc and free, has allocated storage duration. The memory used for this is called the heap, although that is something of a misnomer we are stuck with for historical reasons.


The above is a common scheme used for C implementations, but the C standard permits other implementations.
Note that “local” may be an apt description of identifiers with block scope, but “global” is not entirely correct for any identifiers in C other than keywords. C has identifiers with file scope (the name is known throughout its translation unit from the point of declaration on) and external linkage (different declarations of the name in different translation units can be linked to the same entity) but does not have any global identifiers. For an identifier to be truly global, declaring it once in the program would have to make it known throughout the program. C does not have that; to use an identifier in multiple translation units, it has to be declared separately in each unit.

so ,In C, non-local  variables of procedure and function are in static zone only?

@dok: If a variable is defined outside of any function and is not _Thread_local, it must have static storage duration, so it will be stored in a place where objects with static storage duration are stored.

What C languages says is that if a variable is local to a block (be it a function or not) its lifetime ends at the end of the block. A common way, is to use the stack for that, because you just have to pop the variable out of the stack at the end of the block where it is declared.
But an implementation could choose to only store simple variables and addresses in the stack and use the static zone or the heap for arrays if on a specific system the size of the stack had to be kept minimal. Provided the observable results of the program are the same, an implementation is free to do anything.
